# How to fix Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'undefined' error

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I am trying to run the following mentioned code, I am getting this error,

> 500 Internal Error Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'undefined'

```
  const JSOnobj = req.body.JSOnobj;
  console.log(JSOnobj);
```

Output of `console.log(JSOnobj);` -->

```
`[{"id":2,"updated_order":1},{"id":3,"updated_order":2},{"id":1,"updated_order":3}]`
```

Comment: Try `const upOrders = JSON.parse(req.body.upOrders);`

Comment: Glad I could help, posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, your `JSOnobj` is a string. You need to parse it before operating on it:

```
const upOrders = JSON.parse(req.body.upOrders);
```